# Multiple posts nodejs

Tags: node.js

I currently use this code to make a post.

```
router.post('/klant', function (req, res) {
tafel.query('INSERT INTO details SET klant = "'+req.body.klant+'"', function (err, rows) { });
```

How can i make multiple posts from one page using nodejs ?

if found this

```
  app.post('/:action', function (req, res) {
    if (req.param('action') === 'registration') {
        // ...
    }
});
```

I do not understand what the req.param('action') does and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The req object represents the HTTP request and has properties for the request query like parameters, body or headers.

As you can see in the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param), the `req.param` is deprecated and you can use `req.params` or `req.body` instead.

For instance, if you have a route `/action/:action`:

```
app.post('/action/:action', function(req, res) {
  ...
}
```

The "action" property is available as `req.params.action`.